# Нужны ли кавычки?

Tags: кавычки

Запустил несколько заводов с "нуля"...

Если смотреть в истоки, данная фраза взята из японской философии Кайдзен. Расшифровка весьма проста: Кай — изменения, Дзен — хорошо (лучшее).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Кавычки здесь уместны, так как фразеологизм НАЧАТЬ С НУЛЯ изменён по воле автора высказывания и употреблён в сочетании ЗАПУСТИЛ "С НУЛЯ".

В нацкорпусе встречается двоякое оформление "с нуля" в подобных случаях - и с кавычками , и без. Думаю, что гибкость обусловлена очень частым  употреблением слов С НУЛЯ без глагола НАЧАТЬ, в сочетании с другими глаголами и существительными. Кавычки постепенно сдают позиции. Так что, если Вы их не поставите, грубой ошибки не допустите.

Answer (score 1):

Аленка, если вы имеете в виду выражение "начать с нуля", то кавычки не нужны.

***Дополнение***

Кавычки при необычно употребляемых словах рассматриваются как факультативный знак. Один из основных критериев при употреблении кавычек рассматриваемого типа: ***"обычность/необычность" или, другими словами, «"привычность/непривычность".*** Но разграничить ***"привычное" и "непривычное"*** значения слова зачастую очень трудно. Грамота.ру предлагает руководствоваться следующими правилами при использовании кавычек: ***1) ориентироваться на словарные статьи в толковых словарях русского языка:*** ***если слово (словосочетание) в них уже зафиксировано, следовательно, значение не является непривычным и кавычки не нужны;*** 2) учитывать стиль текста, в котором встречаются подобные лексические единицы. Безусловно, наиболее часто их можно встретить в газетных и журнальных текстах, но при этом в «серьезных» СМИ, предлагающих читателям материалы на общественно-политические и социально значимые темы, постановка кавычек при необычно употребляемых словах более уместна, чем, например, в газетах и журналах, ориентированных на молодежную аудиторию и пишущих на «легкие» темы, поскольку при употреблении слова в «непривычном» значении оно чаще имеет разговорную или просторечную окраску.

Выражение "с нуля" уже зафиксировано словарями, и, следовательно, кавычки не нужны.

Кстати, Грамота.ру. не рекомендует кавычки.

> ***Ответ справочной службы русского языка***
>
> ***Слова *с нуля* в кавычки не заключаются.***